# decouple JavaScript from aspx web form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am currently tasked with cleaning up a website for a client that is built using asp.net web forms. The problem is it's spaghetti code. There are hundreds of lines of JavaScript in the default.aspx page. It was a hassle to simply update the Jquery files in the project. I am trying to find either a framework or method to decouple the JavaScript from the aspx page but I am having trouble finding any such thing.

Is there a way to decouple the JavaScript from this page to clean it up and hopefully make the scripts reusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step, you can create a `.js` file( lets say `app.js`). Typically your html page will have `<script>` tags like this: `<script type="text/javascript"> function().... blah blah </script>`. You can copy all the text between `<script>` tags and paste it into `app.js`. Delete everything between `<script></script>` including the tags.

NOTE: you may have multiple `<script>` tags like above...you can repeat the above process for all the tags and start appending it into `app.js`.

After copying and deleting content from `<script>` tags...in the HTML page, we require to refer to `app.js`. To do this, create a script tag like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="relative/path/to/app.js">`. That's it!

To test if your relative path correctly works: try to point your browser to your relative path for example:`www.example.com/.../relative/path/to/app.js`, if your browser displays app.js code then you are all set.

You can go a step further and modularize your js code etc. See [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.htm): lIMHO this is a good start
Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thank you! I'll start moving over the JavaScript to a separate file and let you know how it goes.